# differential equation system of a function sequence

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am thinking a sequence of real-valued functions

> $F_o(x)=f_o$, $$F_n(x)=f_o+\int^x_{x_o} sF_{n-1}(s)ds$$

I don't know how to calculate $F_n(x)$. What I have in mind is this should be solved by induction.

> $F'_1(x)=xF_0(x)$

> $F''_2(x)=F_1(x)+xF'_1(x)=F_1(x)+x^2F_0(x)$

But this would lead to $F^{(n)}_n(x)$ which I don't think has anything to do with sovling the ODE.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Assume there exists a convergent power series centred about $x_0$ for $F_{n-1}$ and $F_{n}$. Substitute that into the IVP,
$$\begin{aligned} F_{n}'(x) &= x\,F_n(x) = (x - x_0)\,F_{n-1}(x) + x_0\,F_{n-1}(x),\\ F_{n}(x_0) &= f_0, \end{aligned}$$
and you should be able to relate the power series of $F_n$ in terms of the power series for $F_{n-1}.$ Since your initial function in the sequence $F_0$ has a finite power series, you will find so will all of the $F_n.$